# dyLegend align left within a shiny-app

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I want to place the legend of a `dygraph` within a `shiny` app on the left hand side of the plot (within the `dygraph`). My problem is that I cannot set the absolute width of the `dygraph` since the app runs at different screens with different resolutions.

The code may be like that:

ui.r:

```
library(dygraphs)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    dygraphOutput("dygraph")
  )
 )
))
```

server.r

```
library(dygraphs)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
  dygraph(discoveries)
 })
})
```

Is there a way of getting the `width` of the `dygraph`? Or maybe a more simple solution of aligning the legend to the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the legend to the top-left then you can use the following CSS:

```
.dygraph-legend {
  left: 70px !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

You could also easily add this to your code using `tableHTML::make_css`:

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)
library(dygraphs)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
 tags$style(make_css(list('.dygraph-legend', 
                          c('left', 'background-color'), 
                          c('70px !important', 'transparent !important')))),
 titlePanel("Simple example"),
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
   dygraphOutput("dygraph", width = '80%')
  )
 )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
  lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
  dygraph(lungDeaths)
 })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you wanted to chage the width of the dygraph container you could use the argument width in `dygraphOutput`

Comment: While your code only affects the `width` of the `mainPanel`, the trick with CSS-styling works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are very welcome, glad I could help. I changed the answer to show the code that solves your problem i.e. the CSS trick. I also added a neat way to include CSS styles via R code in the ui (just in case it helps).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to use `column` and choose the width from 1 to 12. Here is the ui.R code with 2 for the legend and 10 for the dygraph.

```
library(dygraphs)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Simple example"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            column(2,
                h3("My Legend")
            ),
            column(10,
                dygraphOutput("dygraph")
            )
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: This only gives me space for an legend OUTSIDE the dygraph. But I want to align the legend within the dygraph. Also you probably meant the code for the ui.r instead of server.r